# What is the relationship between HTML events and DOM events

Tags: html, angular, dom

I am learning Angular currently and got confused about the events.
For example, the "mouse click" event is `click`  in DOM Events, but in HTML Events, it is `onclick`.

My question is that what is the difference between `click` and `onclick`?
What is the relationship between HTML Events and DOM Events?
Thanks

Comment: 'click' is the type of the event you can pass to 'addEventListener'. 'onclick' is the name of the html attribute. They do the same - running your code.